# Where to put function/method to test result of SQL Query

Tags: symfony

I continue to struggle with Symfony in regards to where to put some logic and functions.

In this case, I have a simple query.  I want to know how many "Profiles" depend on an address.
the query:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM beneficiary_profile AS bp
JOIN person AS p ON bp.beneficiary_id = p.id
JOIN contact_address AS ca ON p.contact_address_id = ca.id
WHERE ca.id = 2108 -- address id
```

the poor way of doing this [in my controller] with entity methods is this

```
$dependant = 0;
foreach ($address->getPeople() as $person) {
    if ($person->getBeneficiaryProfile() !== null) {
        $dependant++;
    }
}
```

ultimately, this serves as a flag to print a warning about editing a dependent address record.

My first thought was to add a new method to the entity, `$address->isDependent()` that would return `bool` based on `($count > 1)` but this would require me to get the entity repository from the entity.

Soon there will be a whole host of logic to go with unlinking then deletion (or not) to prevent orphan records.  The logic is not as simple as cascading as there can be many people between the address and profile.  there is a house record in the mix as well.

Should I just build my query in the address repository, then set the flag in the controller? (twig reads the flag and displays the warring or not)

Comment: Yes, create a new method in `address` repository and use it. Simple and clear.

Comment: I understand to put the query in the repository, and it will return `int` via `getSingleScalarResult()`. should I just do something like `$dependant = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(ContactAddress::class)->getDependencyCount($address->getId());` and `if ($dependant > 1)`

Comment: Correct logic. What stops you from using it?

Comment: code re-use - maybe I am getting to caught up in the next issue....  I'll do it like this and see what happens next.

Comment: if nothing else it took 33 query's down to 7. (but I knew that would happen ;))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity repository is the class which holds all your queries to database related to some entity, in your case it is `address`. So, **yes**, you should create new method in `AddressRepository` and use where you need.

Not sure what you mean by code reuse, you can get repository almost everywhere in symfony classes. So, you write something like

```
$count = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository(ContactAddress::class)
    ->getDependencyCount($address->getId());
```

And use this `$count` variable in your code. As I already said it is simple and clear.

And in symfony4 you can inject even the repository in your controller, so code can be reduced to something like:

```
public function __construct(AddressRepository $repo)
{
    $this->repo = $repo;
}

public function someAction()
{
    $count = $this->repo->getDependencyCount($address->getId());
}
```

Comment: as for code reuse, I would check this for both "new" and "update" pages.  I also check the "dependency's" for removal and replacing.  As I said, I'll just put the logic in the controller and go from there